# Is it possible to run AWS ECS scheduled task manually?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have daily cron task in the ECS. Sometimes, I need to run it `one-off` manually. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the CLI to do this. For an ECS Fargate task, it looks like this:

```
> aws --profile YOUR_IAM_PROFILE ecs run-task --task-definition TASK_DEFINITION --cluster ECS_CLUSTER --network-configuration '{"awsvpcConfiguration":{"subnets":["subnet-SUBNET_ID"],"securityGroups":["sg-SECURITY_GROUP_ID"],"assignPublicIp":"ENABLED"}}' --launch-type FARGATE --propagate-tags TASK_DEFINITION --overrides '{"containerOverrides":[{"name":"YOUR_CONTAINER","command":["YOUR", "CMD", "OVERRIDE", "HERE"]}]}'
```

You can learn more about the CLI skeleton from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-skeleton.html) and see the JSON values available for "run-task" using

```
> aws ecs run-task --generate-cli-skeleton
```